# Evaluating the complex integral- Correct approach?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm asked to evaluate the following complex integral with C being the unit circle:

$$\oint_{C}^{}{\log(z-z_0)dz}\quad |z_0|>1$$

$\log(z-z_0)$ is multivalued and has a branch point at $z=z_0$. However, this lies exterior to the contour C, hence Cauchy's Theorem is applicable. Therefore,

$$\oint_{C}^{}{\log(z-z_0)dz}=0\quad |z_0|>1$$

Is my approach to this problem valid? I'm a bit rusty and wanted to get some advice.

Comment: It looks fine to me as the  function isn't integrated around a path containing the zero of its variable and it is analytic there.

Comment: Awesome thanks.

Comment: I posted a comment and it was deleted and based on it the OP post modified!  The problem was with $z_0 >1$ and pointed out this a s a question " if $z_0$ is complex,  what does $z_0>1$? My question is :who did delete the comment  and why?  This is very serious accident!!